# I'm looking for equivalent of python set() for pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I am looking for equivalent of python set() function for pandas dataframe.

Some time ago I set list of tuple like below:

`list(set([(11, 11),  (21, 11), (11, 11)]))`

Now my data looks like 
`[(11, 11, timestamp()),  (21, 11, timestamp()), (11, 11, timestamp())]`

and I decided to create dataframe and run

`df.drop_duplicates(subset=['source', 'target'], keep='first')`

But order of `df.drop_duplicates` must be the same like in `list(set())`

Somebody have any idea what can I do?

Comment: set has no order, by definition

Comment: A set is an unordered bag of unique values. Therefore you cannot rely on order while using `set`. The order can even change between different runs of the same code.